# How do I prevent a 404 with dynamic routes in NextJS 13?

Tags: next.js

I have a Next13 app with an incredibly simple folder structure:

```
- app
  - users
    - [id]
      - page.tsx
  - ...
```

And a `page.tsx` with content similar to the following:

```
export default function UserPage({ params }) {
    return <div>{params.id}</div>
}
```

However, when I run `next dev` and go to `/users/1`, I get a 404. Is there something I'm missing about how dynamic routes work in NextJS 13?

Comment: You are not missing anything, from the details you provided it should work exactly as you did it, there's no reason for it to return a 404.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, the problem was in the locale settings. This is a known [bug](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46841) in version 13.2.x.

A temporary way to fix this is to remove the locale settings in `next.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
// i18n: {
//   locales: ["en"],
//   defaultLocale: "en"
// },
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: Can't freaking believe that this stupid config took so many hours of my life. App dir is NOT stable.

Comment: Thanks! Save me a ton of time.